# JPA not fetching data that reflects state of database

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, java-ee-8

I have encountered a curious bug or feature while writing code. Here's the situation:

We are using a PostgreSQL database, EclipseLink in a JavaEE project.

What I am doing in this part of the project is fetching an entity from the database i.e.:

```
User user = userController.get(userId);
```

Which then goes to our controller and fetches the user via a TypedQuery:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class UserController {
private EntityManager em;

    public User get(Integer userId){
        User retval = null;
        TypedQuery<User> = em.createNamedQuery("User.findByUserId", User.class);
        q.setParameter("userId", userId);
        retval = q.getSingleResult();
    }

    public User update(final User modified){...}
}
```

And in my User class I have:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findByUserId", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id = :userId"),
```

So the call goes, I get my user object with its respective data from the database.

In the class where I called the userController.get method I continue to modify the data on this object, and call our controller again to update this data on the database

```
user.setServiceId(1); //any id (integer) pointing to an existing service, this is a ManyToOne relationship
userController.update(user);
```

And here is where it gets funny. In our update method inside the controller class I have my modified User object and using this object I get the primary key userId and fetch the data again from the database to get the original:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class userController {
    private EntityManager em;

    public User get(Integer userId){...}

    public User update(final User modified){
        User retval = null;
        if(modified != null){
            try {
                User original = get(modified.getId()); //Here I fetch the current state of the DB
                if(original != null){
                    Set<Modifications> modifications = apply(original, modified); //Method to apply modifications
                retval = em.merge(original); //Merge changes into database
                em.flush(); //Force data to be persisted
             catch(Exception e){
            }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

However, the fields in the `original` object do not reflect the state of the database but instead contains the same data as the `modified` object. In this case, the `serviceId` on the database is `null`, and in the `modified` I set it to an ID. The `original` has its `serviceId` set to the same value as the `modified` object even though it should contain the fetched data from the database, in this case `null`

My current solution is to construct a new User object, after fetching the user from the database, and modify the data on that new object:

```
User user = userController.get(userId);
User newUser = new User(user);
newUser.setService(service);
userController.update(newUser);
```

Now when I do the update method, the `original` reflects the state of the database.

Or maybe it reflects the state of the `user` object that already exists in the persistence context?

But why does this happen? Since I do make a new `get` call with a `SELECT` statement to the database in my update method.

Comment: How are you getting an EntityManager for each call within the UserControler? Looks like it is using the same EntityManager for both calls - this isn't truly stateless, and subsequent get calls using the same ID aren't really going to the database. You can prove this by comparing the == on the instances you have in the methods. original== modified == retval.

Comment: You're right, after looking more closely, the original and modified objects have the same reference in the debugger, pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same EntityManager for everything, both the read and the 'merge', which in this case is then a no-op. Everything read in through an EM is managed, so that if you read it back again, you get the same instance back. As long as the User isn't being serialized, it is 'managed' by the EntityManager it was read from, and so that same instance, and its changes, are visible on any get calls on that ID.

You didn't show how you are getting EntityManagers, but I would guess is isn't container managed, as they would inject a new one for these calls, and then close them for you when done. You haven't shown any transaction logic on how the update and the em context it is using are hooked up, but I would suggest you create a new EntityManager for these calls. Flush also seems unnecessary, as if update is wrapped in a transaction, should handle flushing the update statement to the database without this extra call.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The problem was solved by changing the `@Stateless` annotation on the Processor that is calling the UserController update method to `@RequestScoped`, which is something we were planning on doing anyway since we were using some annotations wrongly. I should have included these details in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

If `user.setServiceId(1);` is called when the "user" entity is managed, the call is going to update the database row.

you can check the [manage entity lifecycle](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/persistence-intro004.html)

Comment: But these changes are not reflected in the database until the request is done? When going through the request while debugging, the database is not updated until the response is sent back. So the EM is pointing to a 'cached' version of the entity, even when doing a second get and assigning it to a different managed entity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `refresh` the data after saving it to the database and to get the latest state of the object, as `em.refresh(retval)`

You can find the code added below.

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class userController {
    private EntityManager em;

    public User get(Integer userId){...}

    public User update(final User modified){
        User retval = null;
        if(modified != null){
            try {
                User original = get(modified.getId()); //Here I fetch the current state of the DB
                if(original != null){
                    Set<Modifications> modifications = apply(original, modified); //Method to apply modifications
                retval = em.merge(original); //Merge changes into database
                em.flush(); //Force data to be persisted
                em.refresh(retval); // This will fetch the updated data from database
             catch(Exception e){
            }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately this is not the issue I am after. The problem already arises when I fetch the 'original' User from the database, before the merge and flush. When looking into the object while debugging, the object then already has the serviceId, even though it was not written to the database yet, which should only happen later with the merge and flush methods. In my test-case the serviceId on the 'original' User should be null but it already has a serviceId.